# PowerShell task won't use VSTS Task Group variables but does - why?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

We are using Slack to notify our development teams about production code releases. The way we've found to do this that allows us the most flexibilty is through a POST to our Slack app. In the body of the request I'm passing in 4 values, shown below, that are set up as parameters for the task group.

In the task group I have set up 3 parameters with default values, they are:
Name             value

- applicationname $(Release.DefinitionName)
- envionment     $(environment)
- team           $(System.TeamProject)

[Task Group Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3eUL.png)

I set up both a PowerShell script task to run inline. It does not have the option to pass in parameters. Right now I'm just writing the values to the console to see what's going on.

- Write-Output "env $env:environment"
- Write-Output "releaseurl $env:releaseurl"
- Write-Output "team $env:team"
- Write-Output "application $env:applicationname"

[PowerShell Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM2ns.png)

With my Bash script, I am doing the same using echo, and it looks like this:

- echo env $(environment)
- echo releaseurl $(Release.ReleaseWebURL)
- echo team $(team)
- echo application $(applicationname)

[Bash Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ceq07.png)

When I run these scripts PowerShell will only print a value for environment (which is defined in the release workflow). It is failing to use the default release variables, even.

- 2019-04-11T13:23:58.6833137Z env production
- 2019-04-11T13:23:58.6987109Z releaseurl
- 2019-04-11T13:23:58.6997009Z team
- 2019-04-11T13:23:58.6999878Z application

Bash, however, performs as expected.

- 2019-04-11T13:24:17.3299022Z env production
- 2019-04-11T13:24:17.3404876Z team App Services
- 2019-04-11T13:24:17.3405018Z application Release Notification Pilot
- 2019-04-11T13:24:17.3838219Z releaseurl https://thereleaseurl

Bash does not have an issue using the System/Release variables. PowerShell will only use whatever variables it finds explicitly defined in the VSTS Release Variables. I want it to use the values of the task group parameters which will allow the teams to use default or custom values.

So, the PowerShell script would use the applicationname variable, which is defaulted to $(Release.DefinitionName). In the release workflow, teams could leave this as is, or use a custom value if the definition name isn't clear enough or desired for the reported name in the alert. The only way I can get this to work is define applicationname in the release variables, and set its default there to $(Release.DefinitionName).

Again, the bash script works great. The powershell script doesn't seem to like this. Does anyone have an idea on why? Will be happy to try about anything.

Answer (score 1):

The `$env:variable` syntax makes powershell retrieve the values from the environment variables at runtime. The `$(variable)` syntax performs the inlining of variables before handing the script to powershell.

Hence the `$env:variable` isn't captured as a variable usage for the task group, while `$(variable)` is.

The inlining-before-execution can cause issues when the variables contain quotes or other special characters that require escaping.

Ideally you'd pass the variables as arguments to the script invocation and not as inline values in the script block.

When running a script-block, you can explicitly register the variables you want to make available in the Environment Variable section:

[image]

Comment: You'd put the variables in the Environment Variables tab with a `Name`, then reference them in your script using `$env:NameInVariablesTab`. Assign the values using `$(name)`,

Comment: Thanks. I meant to include this in the original post. 

I tried this, but it doesn't really accomplish much. I can put, for example:

name     value
releaseurl  $(Release.ReleaseWebUrl)

and the value will appear. However, the teams won't be able to modify this value without modifying the entire task group. 

I need to use the value that's 1) the default of the task group or 2) the value set in the release workflow. Setting the environment variables here do not allow the flexibility of changing the value without changing it for the entire task group. Parameters of the task group do.

Comment: Here's what I have:

Task Group Parameter 
name, value
applicationname, $(System.TeamProject)

PowerShell Task in Task Group environment variable
name, value
applicationname, $(applicationname)

value being used in script such as:
Write-Output "$env:applicationname"

This does not write the value from the default parameter in the task group like bash does.

Comment: Try all-uppercase

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but no change. The inline script does a Write-Output "$env:APPNAME" where APPNAME is an environment variable defined in the powershell task, and its value is $(APPNAME). APPNAME is defined as a parameter for the task group which has a value as $(Release.DefinitionName) and shoudl display the definition name. 

This works flawlessly in bash. I can not, for the life of me, get it to work with powershell.